# Compiling STXXL on visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, stxxl

I am trying to use STXXL map in my c++ code in visual studio 2015.

I followed the instruction on http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/tags/master/install_windows.html' 
and when I try to build the project in visual studio I get this message:

"<"hash_map">" is deprecated and will be REMOVED. Please use . You can define _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS to acknowledge that you have received this warning."

I tried to add _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS to the preproseccor definitions but it did not help.
It lookes like the problem comes from the file hash_map in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include" directory.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks,
Rachel.

Comment: If this is a warning while building STXXL I would ignore it.

Comment: It is not a warning but an error...